# How to add entries in history tab in quality center for requirement tracebility

Tags: hp-quality-center

I want to add the logs for the requirement history for the changes in the requirement tracebility. Currently,the logs for the changes in the requirement tracebilyt are not being captured in the history section.

Is any code or API to make changes in the requirement tracebility visible in the history tab?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

History is not maintained for requirement traceability in QC. What you can do, enable history for comment field from customization and change your qc workflow script such that it adds comment (i.e. added link/removed link with ids)  when somebody changes anything in requirement traceability section.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the Related field history enabled and to do so, you have to have administration rights on the project.
then go to Tools>Customization>Project Entities> Test Cases
then find your field in either the System Fields list or the User Fields list.
select the target field, in the RHS you will see the field properties and one of the properties is History Enabled. check that option and Save then Hit Return.
Log out of the project and re-Login.

now changes to that field will be tracked and appear in the History tab.